# -moz and -webkit css no longer needed?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have been using the `-moz` and `-webkit` css styles for a while now for things like box shadow, text shadow, etc. And lately I have noticed that each FireFox, Chrome, Safari, and IE (*9*) all yield the same results with the standard `box-shadow` and `text-shadow` and similar css styles.

I was wondering if this is documented anywhere. Because I successfully removed all of the browser-specific ones from a site and it still looks the same in all four of those browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the version of the browsers you are targeting.

It sounds like if, and only if, your app or site is intended to only work on the very latest versions of all the browsers, you can afford to omit the -moz and -webkit on the specific properties you have tested.

There are other properties that aren't supported on all browsers, e.g. my personal favourite [webkit-transition](http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/).   Of course in actual reality it's unlikely you can get away with targetting only the latest browsers unless you're making a personal project.

Comment: Well. I suppose this could be debated until we are all blue in the face - but IE9 is not the only 'ugprade' people need to do. People in general should try to keep their browsers up to date when possible, so I don't really think it is a bad idea to use a tool like `modernizr` to check for this kind of thing even in FireFox and Chrome, and alert the user that they are using an old version.

Comment: But yes, I do understand what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

The latest browsers support these css3 properties by default. These -moz and -webkit specials should however still be used for backwards compatibility with older browsers. Older browsers implemented these to allow the use of these properties before they became standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write that much and still want backwards compatibility: [less.css](http://lesscss.org/) could be your friend.

Another thing: w3schools.com has an up-to-date database for all CSS commands and which browser supports it. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to keep them for older browsers that don't have the standards, but do have the -moz and -webkit css styles.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari that is true.

However, for people using earlier versions of the browsers (Firefox 3.6, as an example) you would still need to leave the `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes.
If you want to target them, you shouldn't remove them.
These properties are progressive enhancement though, so removing them would not be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is to keep them all in there,

example:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

depending on the user's browser version, they will still see the border-radius, older browsers will still use the -moz and -webkit version, the latest versions of safari / firefox or chrome will use the final implementation of the border-radius property.

Comment: That wasn't the question though. 75% of your code might be redundant. Not very efficient..

Comment: redundant on any browser version starting the one that stopped using these flags. anyone without an updated chrome / safari will be having issues if you remove them. It was just a tip for the person asking questions, he can decide for himself whether the users of his site use the latest browsers or not. In fact, it is an answer, when asking if they are no longer needed, i gave him the answer that still some users have an older version and might need the flags. So they are in fact still of use to some people! 75% of my code, is big exageration, not all my code is webkit/moz specific css.