# Gradient background is not working with Chrome

Tags: cross-browser, css

Hello I am using following code that works fine with Firefox, but does not work in Chrome.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

I used WebKit also, but still it's not working.

Comment: This is easily the best css gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - You can also take your current core and import that to colorzilla's ultimate gradient editor to create crossbrowser gradient based on it.

Answer (score 2):

Each browser has different syntax for gradient backgrounds. This code should cover the most widely used browsers:

```
#gradient {
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#CAF579), to(#73CA08));
    /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #CAF579, #73CA08);
    /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CAF579FF, endColorstr=#73CA08FF);
    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CAF579FF, endColorstr=#73CA08FF)";
}
```

You can see more here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

For chrome you would have to use `-webkit-gradient` instead of `-moz-linear-gradient`. Note that it also has a different syntax, e.g. something like this:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom , from(#CAF579), to(#73CA08)) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

See this page for more examples: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

Answer (score 0):

Some versions (new versions) of chrome identify the standard syntax instead of `-webkit`  i.e

```
background: linear-gradient(center top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

So you should always include this with combination to `-moz` and `-webkit` (for compatibility with older versions) like:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background: linear-gradient(center top , #CAF579, #73CA08) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

check this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7512891/1577396) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

CSS gradients have a bit complicated syntax.

There are 5 of different syntaxes - 4 deprecated ones (old ie `filter`, newer ie `-ms-filter`, old webkit `-webkit-gradient`, newer mozilla `-moz-linear-gradient` (plus a set of vendor prefixes to work with different browsers (`-moz-`, `-webkit-`, `-ms-`, `-o-`)) and unprefixed standard `linear-gradient` (which has major difference from previous versions in handling gradient angles).

In your case, for Google Chrome  **you need to add `-webkit-linear-gradient` to your css**. Plus, unprefixed version, because its expected, that Chrome and Safari will support standard syntax *soon*.

Refer to MDN for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient